# Multiple simultaneous connections DotNetCore

Tags: mysql, .net-core, transactionscope, n-tier-architecture

I want to use TransactionScope for my business services in my dotnet core project.
I use both of MysqlConnection and SqlConnection.
My purpose is adding some data my own database and do couple of operations on the client database.

```
 using TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope();
 var addDatabase = await _databaseRepository.AddDatabase(mappedEntity);
 await _realDbService.CreateDatabaseOnRemote(dto);
 scope.Complete();
```

This one is my service's code example.
Each repository do their own crud operations.
I have tried to close connection which is done.

But I have an error which is Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I used a solution for this problem but I'm not sure that it's best solution.

I used Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted event If transaction complete then I call my method inline a scope .

```
               using TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope();

                addDatabaseResult = await _databaseRepository.AddDatabase(mappedEntity);
                Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += delegate
                {
                    using TransactionScope scopeInline = new TransactionScope();
                    _realDbService.CreateDatabaseOnRemote(dto);
                    scopeInline.Complete();

                };
                scope.Complete();
```